# Нумерация элементов localStorage при удалении элементов

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Я пытаюсь сделать нумерованный список дел на js. То есть, к каждому заданию добавляется номер(1,2,3), а задания хранятся в хранилище. Как сделать, чтобы при удалении какого-либо задания все номера переставлялись по новой? Важно чтобы и в хранилище значения изменялись, потому что по этому параметру задания удаляются. (То есть, если номер задания, где вызвана функция, совпадает с номером задания в хранилище, то оно удаляется).
Возможно вопрос глупый, но я по этой теме ничего не нашла, а самостоятельно решить не могу.

Comment: @РустамГимранов нет, каждое задание - объект, у него параметры, а номер среди них. То есть он записывается как параметр элемента в массиве в хранилище

Comment: можно хранить в storager - массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть такая функция splice(id, cnt) - принимает 2 параметра, где первым параметрм идет id позиции в массиве, а второй говорит сколько элементов начиная с него надо удалить, после извлечения объекта ключи массива будут сброшены автоматически,

```
var mass = ['a','b','c']; 
mass.splice(0, 1);
console.log(mass);
//[b,c]
```